# how can i execute scrapy script in php?

Tags: php, python, scrapy, web-development-server

this my spider , i run it with the command " scrapy crawl quotes " in main directory of the project ("/home/zouhir/scrap/sot") (sot is the name of the project)

```
  import scrapy
  class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "quotes"
  start_urls = [
'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
 ]

def parse(self, response):
for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
    yield {
        'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
        'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
        'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
    }
```

and this is my php file "t.php"

```
 <?php
 echo " hello the world ";
 chdir("/home/zouhir/scrap/sot");
 $output = shell_exec('scrapy crawl got');
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
 ?>
```

i got no result from this , how can i have an output(table) when i execute t.php ?

Comment: unless you're running under php_cli I expect php doesn't have permissions to exec that location. Are you seeing `<pre></pre>` in your view source? add apache/http user to the group that owns `/home/zouhir/scrap/sot`

Comment: also managing database connections is a subject very widely covered online, so it's hard to know where to begin. Get `/home/zouhir/scrap/sot scrapy crawl got` to work into page output first. then at the same time learn how to connect to a database (they are unrelated really).